# Swift 3.0: Does calling `sync` on a queue after calling `async` block the queue?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I was going through the revisions in the [Swift document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID545) and found the following

> If you need to capture and mutate an in-out parameter, use an explicit local copy, such as in multithreaded code that ensures all mutation has finished before the function returns.

```
func multithreadedFunction(queue: DispatchQueue, x: inout Int) {
    // Make a local copy and manually copy it back.
    var localX = x
    defer { x = localX }

    // Operate on localX asynchronously, then wait before returning.
    queue.async { someMutatingOperation(&localX) }
    queue.sync {}
}
```

I had two questions concerning this:

1. Does calling `async` and then calling `sync` block the queue?
2. Why would you call `async` in the first place if you wanted to wait? I always thought asynchronous tasks were to return immediately without waiting until the whole code block was executed. Shouldn't one call `sync`?

**EDIT** Added link to the document. BTW I don't think whether `queue` is serial or concurrent is not too relevant.

Comment: Is the queue serial or concurrent?

Comment: i think the point is that you dont know what type of queue it is... but this code still stumps me as to why an empty `queue.sync{}` would be called directly after an async. maybe its a mistake in the document lol. i agree with your point 2

Comment: @kennytm I have no idea. It's from the Swift document

Comment: ive submitted feedback on the document about it, maybe it really is a mistake, will see if they respond

Comment: This code only makes sense if the queue is a serial queue as this will ensure that the function waits until the async operation is complete before returning

Comment: A dispatch group and a dispatch_group_wait would probably be a better solution as it wouldn't depend on the type of queue